# Pass ssh options to ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm stuck in the *Permission denied (publickey)* hell trying to copy public key to a remote server so Jenkins can rsync files during builds.

Running:

`sudo ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx`

I have done this for another server, but that one has a separate key pair for SSH assigned by EC2, and my current guess is that ssh-copy-id is trying to use wrong private key for this connection. Is there a way to pass **-vv** to **ssh-copy-id** so I can see what jey it's trying to use. I've looked into the -o switch, but can't seem to get it right.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures file/directory permissions which usually always caused me headaches...

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I've done:

added following to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host xx.xx.xx.xx
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-name-for-that-machine.pem
```

Then copied **key-name-for-that-machine.pem** into /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh

Didn't run ssh-copy-id again, simply have rsync use that key file when moving stuff, here's the rsync script:

```
rsync -rvh -e 'ssh -v' "/tmp/project-DEV-${BUILD_ID}/" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx:"/www/www.project-dir.net/"
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess would by running it without sudo. But that's depending on how you normally log into the server.

- If you normally login by using ssh ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx then lose the
  sudo.
- If not than try to login with sudo ssh ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

Reading your question, at least one of these should fail.

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere, with sudo it looks for keys in /root and fails to SSH. The issue must be the key it's trying to SSH with, but I don't know how to tell it which one to use when connecting.

Comment: it will automatically look in your ~/.ssh/id_rsa file for that.

Comment: Yeah, problem is that I have a separate EC2 key for that machine, how do I get around that? I can't believe I didn't document this first time around!